# PHP Quiz not actually checking if answer is correct, rather always saying correct

Tags: php, boolean, boolean-logic

I have this weird issue where my PHP quiz in not checking if the answer the user submitted is actually correct. I know this because when I answer something that is completely off it still replies back with the if correct message and does not implement the link that should show up if answer is wrong. At first I thought it was because I was checking phrases in arrays instead of single words but after testing it with simple single words I got the same result. I am relatively new to PHP and have been searching online but I have only been finding ones related to multiple choice answers not submit text boxes. Here is my code:

**Array list:**

```
<?php
$array['one'] = "Mickey Mouse";
$array['oneone'] = "Oswald the Lucky Rabbit";
?>
```

**Main quiz page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Final Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("newquiz2.php");
 print("{$array['one']} was modeled after what character created by the Disney Studio?<br>");
 print("<form action='newquiz2check.php' method='get'>\n");
 print("<input type='text' name='one'><br><br>\n");
 print("<input type='submit' value='Submit Answer'>\n<br><br>");
 print("</form>\n\n\n");

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Quiz Check:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Answers for Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("newquiz2.php");
if (metaphone($one) == metaphone($oneone)) {
$one = $array['one'];
$oneone = $array['oneone'];
   print("Correct: $one was modeled after $oneone");
   print("<p><a href='newquiz2ask.php'>Play again </a><br><br>");
   }  
else{print("<a href='newquiz2ask.php'>Back to home </a><p>\n");}



?>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything else is working other than this. Am I supposed to use `@GET` to assign a variable to arrays or what? I am not entirely sure if this is how you check submit text boxes.

Comment: Why are you using metaphone() to compare, and where is your form data fetched using $_GET['one'] method. Actually you should store question and answer in a same array with unique ID that will help you to compare and achieve your goal easily.

Comment: also whats in this `include("newquiz2.php");` file??

Comment: @webDev the include is to use the files containing the arrays, since they are separate files I need to be able to call the arrays somehow. As of for the question and answer in the same array with a unique id like this:     $array = array( "left" => "green");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quiz is very **broad application** but based on your try and based on the comments, I have something for you (**VERY BASIC** array based quiz).

**questions.php**

```
<?php
$questions = array(
    array("question"=>"Question number 1", "answer"=>"ans1"),
    array("question"=>"Question number 2", "answer"=>"ans2"),
    array("question"=>"Question number 3", "answer"=>"ans3"), 
);
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        require_once 'questions.php';
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="check.php">
            <?php 
            $random_index = array_rand($questions,1); //gives you only one question index from 3 question list
            ?>
            <label><?php echo $questions[$random_index]['question']; ?></label><br>
            <input name="answer" type="text" /><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="index" value="<?php echo $random_index; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit answer" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**check.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'questions.php';
$entered_answer = $_POST['answer']; //Form input named as answer
$index = $_POST['index'];
if($entered_answer==$questions[$index]['answer']){
    echo "Correct answer";
}
else{
    echo "Incorrect answer";
}
//Redirect link
?>
```

Based on your try, I have created three files, `index.php`, `questions.php` and `check.php`. Try creating these files and run index.php. See the answers in the array and put correct and incorrect answers.

For PHP array, array index is enough for now, but if you gonna store the questions and answer into your DB then you need to have primary key ID to fetch answer and to compare the answer.